# how to extract date using preg match on string with lines

Tags: php, preg-match

How can I extract the date from these two strings.

```
Date: 03/03 - 14:10

text
```

And from

```
    Date/Time: 08/03/16 13:50

Summary of Fault:
```

I have tried

```
$matches = array();
                $pattern = "/^.*\Date\/Time\:\b.*$/m";
                preg_match($pattern, $toParse, $matches);
                echo($matches[0]);

                $matches = array();
                $pattern = "/.*Date:.*/mi";
                preg_match($pattern, $toParse, $matches);
```

Comment: "these two string" ?? Those are same string ?

Comment: Also, in what format do you want your date ?

Comment: You can try with an [optional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) part: `$pattern = '~\bDate(?:/Time)?:\h*(\d[/\d\h:-]+)\b~i';` [See demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/534217). Of course you can also use this with `preg_match`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in order to extract all the matched occurrences, you need to use `preg_match_all()`.
**Pattern for time:**

```
/.[0-9]:.[0-9]/
```

**Patern for Date:**

```
/.[0-9]\/.[0-9]\/.[0-9]/
```

Here is a reference to [preg_match_all](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_preg_match_all.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use preg_match_all

```
'/: (.*?) /'
```

https://regex101.com/r/tY6bT5/1